# C++ undefined namespace

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a header file, implementation file and main file for a simple c++ program that returns the systems hostname using `gethostname()`.

my header file that declares my class, data, and methods

```
//hostname.h
#pragma once                                                                                              

namespace hostnamespace
{
  class hostname_class
  {
    public:
      hostname_class();
      void to_string();

    private:
      char *name;
  };  
}
```

my implementation file that defines my class and methods

```
//hostname_class.cpp
#include "hostname.h"                                                                                     
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <limits.h>

using namespace hostnamespace;
using namespace std;

class hostname_class{
  private:
    char *name;
  public:
    hostname_class(){
      gethostname(name, HOST_NAME_MAX);
    }   
    void to_string(){
      cout << "Hostname:" << &name << endl;
    }   
};
```

my main program file

```
//hostname_main.cpp
#include "hostname.h"                                                                                     
#include <iostream>

using namespace hostnamespace;

int main() {
  hostname_class host;
  host.to_string();
  return 0;
}
```

when I try and run `g++ -o main hostname_main.cpp hostname_class.cpp`

I get this error

```
/bin/ld: /tmp/ccGfbyuu.o: in function `main':
hostname_main.cpp:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `hostnamespace::hostname_class::hostname_class()'
/bin/ld: hostname_main.cpp:(.text+0x2b): undefined reference to `hostnamespace::hostname_class::to_string()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're replicatring the class declaration of `hostname_class` in both the header and cpp. Don't do that. Just implement the members in the cpp . In case you're wondering how on earth this compiled to the point of link failure, you have two `hostname_class` classes: one in the `hostnamespace` namespace, and one in the global namespace. The code in `hostname_class.cpp` implements the one in the global namespace, while the `using namespace hostnamespace;` in `main.cpp` pulls in the other one (which you never defined).

Comment: Try to first make it work without adding a namespace to complicate things. For that matter, you don't need a class to complicate things, either. All you need is a function.

Comment: `gethostname` doesn't work this way because C arrays and strings don't work this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are redeclaring the hostname_class in the global namespace instead of defining it within the namespace you intended.

A sample structure of how your hostname_class.cpp file could be written.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include "hostname.h"

using namespace std;

namespace hostnamespace
{

    hostname_class::hostname_class() {
        gethostname(name, HOST_NAME_MAX);
    }   

    void hostname_class::to_string() {
      cout << "Hostname:" << name << endl;
    }   
};
```

**One side note**  - I literally copied your method implementations verbatim. It will compile.  But `name` is certainly uninitialized and pointing to an undefined memory address when you pass it into `gethostname`.  That's probably not good.